# Update TextView before sleeping

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, sleep

I'd like to do `setText()` on a `TextView` and make the activity sleep just after.

Here is the code :

```
tv.setText("myText");
tv.invalidate(); // Doesn't work
pause(1000); // French for sleep
```

And my function pause :

```
public void pause(int seconds)
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        try { 
            this.wait(seconds); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) { 
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the TextView doesn't update before sleeping. I tried to call `invalidate()` on my TextView but it doesn't work.

I have another possible solution : create a new Thread for sleeping the activity, and if the value of my TextView is still the same, reload the Thread, else call my function `pause()`. But is it possible to get the real value of my TextView in the View ? Because I can get the new text when I do :

```
tv.setText("myText");
System.out.println(tv.getText());
pause(1000); // French for sleep
```

Whereas the text doesn't update in the View.

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you need the sleep/pause function for? locking the main thread is never a good idea, instead you should use something like `new Handler().postDelayed(action)` if you just want to run something after a certain time.

Comment: @Jave It's an algorithm which set text and sleep the thread to make this text readable. I didn't find others solutions. After the Thread resume, another text is being shown and sleep the Thread, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest what Jave said.

```
tv.setText("myText");
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something
            }
        }, 3000); //3000 is time in ms.
```

Comment: I understood. But the problem is the action done after the 3000ms is not always the same. I think I will do another function, with steps or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the UI thread and make it sleep for too long , you will get the application-not-responding dialog . of course , only when the function ends , you will see the new value , so this is not a good solution . you can use handlers if you wish to use only the UI thread.

If you use a different thread , you will need to set the text of the TextView somehow using the UI thread since it's the only one that is allowed to do so (use handler for this) .

Comment: Ok thanks, but I make it sleeps for 1 second. So I will use a Handler